# What are the advantages of using db.collection.createIndex() rather than db.collection.ensureIndex()

Tags: mongodb

As mentioned in title, I can see it is told by official MongoDB doc [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/)

,but it doesn't tell us why we should do it this way to create an index in MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ensureIndex()` is just deprecated in 3.0, meaning, it's going away eventually. The reason being, it's basically being renamed to `createIndex()`. There is no difference between them, and the only reason that `ensureIndex()` still exists is so that older code will still work until it's properly updated to the new name.